# Plot different data in the same window Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

Is there a command to *clear* a plot window in Bokeh?

I have a plot window like below:
[image: Plot]

One can click on the datapoints in plot 1 or 2 and then it's corresponding blob is shown in plot 3 however I can't get the figure to clear between selections so everything is simply plotted on top of one another.

Is there a command like so:

```
p3 = figure(plot_width=20, plot_height=20,title="Selected Creature")
p3.line(x=some_data_x, y=some_data_x, line_color='red', source=some_data)

p3.clear() <----- I need this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who come seeking knowledge here's what I did in the end.

To update the figure change the source data like so:

```
p3 = figure(plot_width=20, plot_height=20,title="Selected Creature")
p3.line(x=some_data_x, y=some_data_x, line_color='red', source=some_data)

some_data.data = new_data
```

The figure will auto-update like so:
[image]

Thanks to the Bokeh team for a great package!!